# .f to .f90 error causing 'Unclassifiable Statement at (1)'?

Tags: macos, formatting, fortran, gfortran

I just changed .f to .f90 and compiled with gfortran on my Mac (OSX 10.7) and found it fails compilation on the following line:

```
PartPos(1:3,1+nstart:nstart+npart(1))= pos(1:3, 1 + npart(0)):sum(npart(0:1)))
```

further up it is allocated and defined:

```
real*4,allocatable    :: PartPos(:,:)
...
allocate(PartPos(1:3, 1:Ntot))
```

so it should run fine. The code compiles perfectly when I comment out the first line. My understanding is that the only difference between the two is the formatting (which could affect me). Could someone tell me what I'm missing. Sorry, I'm new to Fortran and have been searching for a solution for quite a while before I came here. Thanks in advance.

My (somewhat useless) error output:

```
  PartPos(1:3,1+nstart:nstart+npart(1))= pos(1:3, 1 + npart(0)):sum(npart(0
  1
  Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Compiled using:

```
>> gfortran program_test.f90 -o program_test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RHS appears to be missing a parenthesis [I see 4 "(" and 5 ")"].

Comment: That is just truncation in the output. The full line is:
PartPos(1:3,1+nstart:nstart+npart(1))= pos(1:3, 1 + npart(0)):sum(npart(0:1)))
Is there a character limit? I have lines longer above it which don't have the same problem.

Comment: Sigma - nailed it. I thought it concatenated the next table this way but my brackets were retarded. I'm not sure if I should just delete this post. Sorry.

Comment: @Griff: Well, you learned something, so why? Also yes, there is still a character limit in free form; I think the standard specifies 132 characters.